# Java .jar file size

Tags: java, selenium, jar

I did a program with selenium webdriver.
I used `selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar` and `selenium-java-2.53.1.jar` in my project.
I used `selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar` for

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 80);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(degisikkaydet)));`
```

I only use `selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1` for `wait.until()`. If I delete it, I can't use `wait.until()`, but that jar file increases the size of my program's .jar by 20mb.  Is there a better option than including `selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1` with my project?

Comment: If you set it up correctly, the size of the Selenium jars shouldn't affect the size of your project jar. They are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Classes `WebDriverWait`, `Wait` and `ExpectedConditions` are located inside `selenium-support` package, which you can download from [Maven central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/2.53.1/) for example, and include in your project instead of `selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1`.

However, I would highly recommend setup your project using one of the build automation systems - Maven, as described on [Selenium site](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp), Gradle, or anything else. Making problems like this one disappear is what those tools are good for.